# How to stop Running Python Code

Tags: windows

Im Running python code which runs continuously and i dont know how to stop the code can any one suggest me Thabks in Advance, im Running Code in Spyder
the Code is as below

```
while True:        # loop forever    
    print('Hello')
```

Im simply printing the Hello continuously but i cant stop the code

Comment: close the console

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-C?

Comment: Btw, since you seem to be new to Python, be sure to get a good IDE. In my opionion, you cannot beat the community edition of JetBrains' [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download) Learn to use the debugger - it is your new best friend :-)

Comment: actually im Runinng the code in Spyder and i even tried ctrl+c but it didn't work but in IDE 3.6.5 ctrl+C is working but why it is not working for Spyder

Comment: You need to terminate the interpreter (in this case Spyder). See [The stop execution button (red square) doesn't always stop execution (looped try statements) · Issue #4786 · spyder-ide/spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4786)